# Use preg_replace to replace a href value and prevent duplicate question mark

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have a code like this :

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', 'my_url_replacer');
function my_url_replacer($content) {     
    $params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if($params) {
        return preg_replace("/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/", "$0?".$params, $content);
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
?>
```

It will append all a href tag values inside the `$content` with the value of the query string from the URL.
For example :

If the page URL is `https://example.com?param1=blue&param2=red` - AND the `$content` contain `<a href="https://example.net">Awesome Button</a>` - it will be replaced with `<a href="https://example.net?param1=blue&param2=red">Awesome Button</a>`

Basically, anything in the query string will be added to the a href tag in the content.

The problem appears when the a href already has query string. For example if the a href value is something like this

```
<a href="https://example.net?tag=zero">Awesome Button</a>
```

the output will be

```
<a href="https://example.net?tag=zero?param1=blue&param2=red">Awesome Button</a>
```

There are two question marks there. How to prevent this duplicate question marks issue if the `a href` value already has question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```php
preg_replace_callback("/(?<=href=[\"'])([^\"'?]+)(?:\?([^\"'?]+))?(?=[\"'])/", function($x) use ($params) {
   return !empty($x[2]) ? $x[1] . '?' . $params . '&' . $x[2] : $x[1] . '?' . $params;
}, $content);
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/jSTSR):

```php
$content = '<a href="https://example.net">Awesome Button</a>
<a href="https://example.net?tag=zero">Awesome Button</a> ';
$params = 'param1=blue&param2=red';
echo preg_replace_callback("/(?<=href=[\"'])([^\"'?]+)(?:\?([^\"'?]+))?(?=[\"'])/", function($x) use ($params) {
   return !empty($x[2]) ? $x[1] . '?' . $params . '&' . $x[2] : $x[1] . '?' . $params;
}, $content);
# => <a href="https://example.net?param1=blue&param2=red">Awesome Button</a>
#    <a href="https://example.net?param1=blue&param2=red&tag=zero">Awesome Button</a>
```

The `(?<=href=[\"'])([^\"'?]+)(?:\?([^\"'?]+))?(?=[\"'])` pattern captures the part of string up to `?`, and the second part is optional (see `?` at the end). If Group 2 matches, the `&` is used to join the `$params` to the resulting value, else, only `?` + `$params` are added to the match.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Just one question left : is there a way to keep the original tag=zero stay in the front of the URL? Expected output : https://example.net?tag=zero&param1=blue&param2=red

Comment: @HendraSetiawan Yes, see [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5u4fc), use `return !empty($x[2]) ? $x[1] . '?' . $x[2] . '&' . $params : $x[1] . '?' . $params;`